# Как поместить результат запроса SQL в переменную (MSSQL)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count  FROM '+@table_name
EXEC (@sql)
```

есть вот такой код, который считает количество строк в нужной мне таблице.

Как поместить это количество в переменную `@cnt`?

Чтобы я смог потом сделать `if @cnt>0...`

Comment: Используйте sp_executesql  вместо exec.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь процедурой `sp_executesql`, которая позволяет передавать и возвращать параметры:

```
DECLARE @Cnt    INT
    , @sql  NVARCHAR(1000)
    , @table_name SYSNAME = 'TableName'

SET @sql = N'SELECT @Cnt = COUNT(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Cnt INT OUTPUT', @Cnt OUTPUT

SELECT @Cnt
```

[sp_executesql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Вообще говоря, для `if @cnt > 0` нет необходимости подсчитывать количество строк в таблицы. С точки зрения производительности лучше использовать запрос вида:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM TableName )...
```

Comment: мб тогда `select top 1 1` ?

Comment: @teran, можно и так, оптимизатор строит абсолютно одинаковые планы для обоих вариантов. Но для какого-то более сложного запроса лучше явно использовать TOP (1), тут Вы совершенно правы.